# How about an "I'm so vain" badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

You could award the vainty badge for someone who looks at their profile more than 50(+/-) times in one day.

Comment: You probably think this feature-request is about you, don't you...

Comment: Funny. But what could behavior would that be promoting?

Comment: How could you tell? =)

Comment: Well, some people are motivated by reputation, so getting them familiar with it early on could improve retention. Then again, this would be a bit excessive for that.

Comment: Wow, yours is the first profile I've ever seen with the About Me section written in third person!

Comment: I'm waiting for one in the second person.

Comment: @Gabe: If Bryan looks at Bryan's profile in the third person, does it not count towards the "I'm so vain" badge?

Comment: @Rick: Maybe he would get a "[User] is so vain" badge?

Comment: @Rosinante We should get `@YOU` to do that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really can't see that this encourages *anything* useful.

However, *I* really wouldn't mind getting a `[stalker]` badge for visiting *your* profile 50+ times in a day...

Comment: I want a `stalked` badge if someone visits my profile more than 100 times.